# Magento 2.2 deprecated module \Magento\Backend\Block\

Tags: php, magento2.2.0, magento2.2-dev, github

As far as I read about Magento's documentation I can't find how all that deprecated content will be replaced. The only information is also displayed in each deprecated class of this module ( \Magento\Backend\Block\ )

```
/**
 * Backend grid item renderer
 *
 * @api
 * @deprecated 100.2.0 in favour of UI component implementation
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
```

Where can I find how these classes will be treaded? for now, my only source is:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/best-practices/semantic_config.html

In which it says that there it will be a new book but not sure if is already out. I have a Huge module in adminhtml where is displayed all my admin content and need to know if there are out there some content to know how to modify all those classes, or should I wait a little more, for upcoming (release maybe?) information from Magento's team

Also if the idea is not cleared with this, here is the deprecated content/classes
https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block

Hope you can give me some light here!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the dev docs have what you want documented. I've successfully used these for admin grid listings and admin edit forms:

#### Form Ui Component (Making an admin edit form)

[Magento DevDocs - Form Component](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-form.html)

The key parts to achieving this are the following:

- Data Source / Data Provider
- Ui Component Definition
- Inserting the Ui Component Definition into Admin Layout XML
- Controller/Actions for CRUD

#### Grid Ui Component (Making an admin grid listing)

[Magento DevDocs - Listing Component](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-listing-grid.html)

The key parts to achieving this are the following:

- Data Source / Data Provider
- Ui Component Definition
- Inserting the Ui Component Definition into Admin Layout XML
- Controller/Action for View (index) page

Comment: All I'm missing how to make a custom form element. For example a custom wysiwyg editor for some feature.